# unpivot multilevel index pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frames as shown below, what I want to do is unpivot the data frame that has multi index . This is what I have tried so far

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[2016, 2016, 2015, 2015], 
                       ['Dollar Sales', 'Unit Sales', 'Dollar Sales', 'Unit Sales'], 
                       [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], columns=[*'ABCD'])
    df['Dates'] = ['date','Dates','10/12','06/08']
    new_labels = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.iloc[:2].T.astype(str), names=['Year', 'Sales'])
    df1 = df.set_axis(new_labels, axis=1).iloc[2:]
    df1 = df1.stack()
    df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

The result I get is

```
Year    level_0 Sales   2015    2016    date
0   2   Dates            NaN    NaN    10/12
1   2   Dollar Sales      3      1      NaN
2   2   Unit Sales        4      2      NaN
3   3   Dates            NaN    NaN     06/08
4   3   Dollar Sales     7       5       NaN
5   3   Unit Sales       8       6       NaN
```

However, what I want the end result to look like is

```
Year level_0    Sales       2015    2016     Dates
    1   2     Dollar Sales    3      1       10/12
    2   2     Unit Sales      4      2       10/12
    4   3     Dollar Sales    7      5       06/08
    5   3     Unit Sales      8      6       06/08
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `df1` lines of code to the following:

```py
# as before, but also stack by column index level 1
df1 = df.set_axis(new_labels, axis=1).iloc[2:].stack(level=1)

# forward fill date column
df1.date.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)

# reset index, same as your code
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

# drop rows where Sales == "Dates"
df1 = df1.loc[df1.Sales.ne("Dates")]
```